# .htaccess redirect reg. Exp

Tags: php, .htaccess

I’m trying to redirect from this URL: (via .htaccess)

***https://example.com/index.php?route=information/blogger&blogger_id=4***

To

***https://example.com/blog/the-new-site***

I’m using this code:

```
rewriterule /index.php?route=information/blogger&blogger_id=4 blog/the-new-site$1 [r=301,nc]
```

But it doesn’t do anything

Am I missing something?

Comment: This certainly will not work. A short glance at that line reveals 4 details that will prevent that. Did you bother to read the documentation of the tool you are using at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=information/blogger&blogger_id=4$
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ /blog/the-new-site [QSD,R=301,L]
```

Such a rule can be implemented in the http server's central host configuration. If you do not have access to that you can instead use a *distributed* coniguration file (often called ".htaccess"). You need to enable the usage of such files for that (see the `AllowOverride` directive in the documentation).